# How to properly restore data when resuming an activity using Firebase Database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm developing an application that display a list of items and allows the users to add more items and check the items' details.

Let's say that I keep my database references in the activity, adding `ChildEventListener` listeners `onResume()` and removing them on `onPause()`:

```
public void onResume() {
   super.onResume();
   mItemChildEventListener = mDatabaseReference.child('items').addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
       public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
           mAdapter.addItem(dataSnapshot.getValue(Item.class));
       }
       ...
   };
}

public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (mItemChildEventListener != null) {
        mDatabaseReference.removeEventListener(mItemChildEventListener);
    }
}
```

In these `ChildEventListener`, I'm adding item by item to the list of items and calling `notifyItemInserted(itemArray.size() - 1)` in the adapter.

```
public void addItem(Item item) {
    if (mItems == null) {
        mItems = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    mItems.add(item);
    notifyItemInserted(mItems.size() - 1);
}
```

Also, to keep the application running smoothly, I'm keeping the list of items in a [Reteiner Fragment](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#RetainingAnObject), saving this values `onSaveInstanceState()` and restoring them on `onCreate()`.

```
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mItems = getState(STATE_ITEMS);
    } else {
        mItems = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    mAdapter = new ItemAdapter(mItems);
}

public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    saveState(STATE_ITEMS, mItems);
}

public <T> T getState(String key) {
    //noinspection unchecked
    return (T) mRetainedFragment.map.get(key);
}

public void saveState(String key, Object value) {
    mRetainedFragment.map.put(key, value);
}

public static class RetainedFragment extends Fragment {
    HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // retain this fragment
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }
}
```

However, if I unregister and register the listener again, for example, by any orientation change or leaving and returting to the activity, as expected, `onResume()` will be called, and by adding the `ChildEventListener` again, the same data is retrieved, which, in case if it's not compared with the data that is already contained in the list of items, `mItems`, it will be duplicated.

Also, if I do not keep the list of items, `mItems`, and retrieve the data every time `onResume()` is called, the list loses its scroll position and also blinks, since it takes some time to retrieve the data.

**Question**

How can I keep the list of items retrieved without retrieving them again again, but keep listening for changes in the items already retrieved and for new items added? Is there a better solution than comparing the items already retrieved with the new items, for example, by their key?

I've tried looking in the documentation and other questions, but I couldn't find any information relevant for this situation. Also, I have tried to keep the reference to `mDatabaseReference` in `onSaveInstanceState()`, as I have done with the list of items `mItems`, but it has't worked either.

Comment: @rewgoes Do you have a DatabaseHelper class and are you using a RecyclerAdapter as a View Holder if so you can load your data in an ArrayList then you only need to make a trip to the DB when you Add Update or Delete so this is a MVP design I use with Sqlite

Comment: @grendel, I'm not using DatabaseHelper. My database is totally based on firebase realtime database.

Comment: @MarianoCórdoba Those patterns alone won't necessarily help the problem the OP is experiencing.  Infrastructure you build that way is still susceptible to being torn down and recreated for each configuration change, unless you still do something special to retain your data model layer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you [enable persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities) in the Firebase Realtime Database SDK, that will help prevent unnecessary fetches of data that's already been received.  The SDK will cache fetch data locally and prefer to use that data first when it's available:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

Be sure to [read the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities) to understand how this works.

Also bear in mind that it's traditional to start and stop listener during onStart and onStop.  This will avoid even more refetches if the app loses focus for a moment (for example, it pops up a dialog, or some other transparent activity appears on top).

Answer (score 2):

1. Just make a Firebase call inside a Loader and save the data in a static variable or list or whatever data structure suits you.
2. Initialize the Loader in onCreate.
3. In the Loader, override the onStartLoading() method and in onStart() call this method.
4. Inside onStartLoading() simply check if the static variable is null or not. If it is null, startLoading. Else do not load, and set the previous data as data source.
5. The advantage of using Loaders is, in case of orientation changes, it won't make network calls as AsyncTask does.

Comment: The OP is using a child listener to continually listen to changes at a particular location in the database.  Given that updates trickle in over time, this strategy won't work very well because Loaders tend to assume that an entire payload of data is loaded just once.

Comment: I agree to what you are saying but what I am saying is regarding the orientation change issue. Keep the child listener registered and use it normally. But read once initially using loaders. And use them when you come back to the app onStart().

Comment: Also as you have written in your answer, we can read once using loader and cache the data and use it offline. But even to cache, you to to read for the first time (even if you don't use the onStart() case and query offline data)

Comment: Firebase child listeners listen continually, and they don't stop until you tell them to stop.  They receive a potentially unlimited set of events over time.  That won't work with a Loader, which assumes a single finite set of data all at once.