# Any way to store a "client object" / realtime listener in Firestore DB?

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a realtime listener object in a variable `query_watch` (see below). I need to access it later so the listener can be detached (unsubscribed).

My approach is the serialize the object first as a string before storing it in Firebase under a specific user collection. However, Firestore specifically cannot do this as when I try to serialize it with `pickle` or `dill` libraries I get the following error:

`_pickle.PicklingError: Pickling client objects is explicitly not supported. Clients have non-trivial state that is local and unpickleable.`

Here is the full code I tried, adapting the code snippets from official docs https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen?authuser=0#python_5 :

```
import threading
callback_done = threading.Event()   
def on_snapshot(doc_snapshot, changes, read_time):  
    for change in changes:
        if change.type.name == 'ADDED':
            print(f'Entry: {change.document.id}')           
            callback_done.set()

query = db.collection("entries").where('cik_code', 'in', ["0001802749"])
query_watch = query.on_snapshot(on_snapshot)
pickled_object = pickle.dump(query_watch)
```

Is there any way around this or anything else I can try?

Comment: Can you have a look at the listen_document, listen_multiple, listen_for_changes functions in this [GitHub link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/a4064e9e1fd2d6eac632b4a341140bce19caa914/firestore/cloud-client/snippets.py#L716-L717)? Try to use the code snippet provided there and see if the error persists.

Comment: Hi @PriyashreeBhadra I have looked at those functions in the docs before. It doesn’t help me as I’m trying to store the listener in Firestore DB, and the only way I know to do this is by serialising first.

Comment: The code for [on_snapshot](https://googleapis.dev/python/firestore/latest/_modules/google/cloud/firestore_v1/document.html#DocumentReference.on_snapshot) shows how the object is constructed in the function.
You could look at changing the function to return a dic data type by altering the on_snapshot function to have change.to_dict() which should allow you to pickle the data returned.
The object "change" will be processed by the "to_dict" function which then returns a serialized output.

Comment: Hi neo5_50, did you try solving the issue with the solution I suggested in the previous comment?

Comment: @PriyashreeBhadra unfortunately there wasn't enough detail in your comment for me to try it out. 
Can you provide a code snippet showing how on_snapshot can return a dictionary which can be retrieved and then converted back to a watch class later?

Comment: Hi neo5_50, please have a look at the answer I posted below. I hope it answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

In the way you explained your issue by the wording in your last reply "watch" class, I think I understand your question better now and the answer is, this won't work - it is similar to this [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46270664/how-to-properly-restore-data-when-resuming-an-activity-using-firebase-database.).

A listener cannot be stored with a precise cursor to the data and resumed from that specific document again in the listener. It is possible to do this with [specific queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query?hl=cs), but this is not applicable to your case. You would have to store the session data in your database and reference that but because firebase is a NoSQL RTDB, the listener can never resume service size without refetching the data.

As mentioned in the other SO questions, to have this functionality of storing the cursor location and resuming from where it left off, the closest method I could find that may work is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47640400/proper-way-to-resume-firebase-eventlistener.).